# Is EPS image editable

Tags: matlab, grid, figure, eps

I converted a matlab fig to eps, I need to add the grid to this figure which now I have in eps format. Is there any possibility. I know I can change the title or labels using ultraedit or similar programs but cant identify the relevant place for grid.

Comment: you could use Adobe Illustrator, Corel Draw, or InkScape or some another vector graphic editor (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_vector_graphics_editors)

Comment: Thanks @Azim InkScape did the job for me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you simply need to read the PostScript program and then modify it to be suitable for your needs.

You will, however, probably need a working knowledge of the PostScript language in order to understand the program and succesfully modify it.